# error pulling from repository with eclipse "illegal char"

Tags: ssh, git, eclipse

I upgraded my eclipse from 2018 to 2019 and nowI'm getting the following when I'm trying to pull from my repository:

> ssh://git@companyserver/nmc/ourproject.git: Illegal char <:> at index 21: C:\Users\Owner.ssh\C:\Users\Owner\id_rsaFoxWork

What does the Illegal Char mean? Is it something to do with my ssh key and the upgraded Eclipse? Cause it worked fine before